# How to remove date fields from amcharts whose valuefield is not present

Tags: amcharts

Take a look at this example chart - http://live.amcharts.com/1ZWY1/edit/

Some of the values for the field are null and don't want to display them. Is there anyway I can get this working in AmCharts.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to show records which don't have value,remove those data from **dataProvider** and

`var categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
        categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing = true;`

or replace null values with 0 , it shows 0 in balloon when hover to that particular date

Answer (score 0):

You should remove those data items from your data and also set equalSpacing:true for your CategoryAxis.